# How to create a list of all possible combinations? c# (variable selection algorithm)

Tags: c#, statistics, regression

This is a bit of a complicated issue for me so I will do my best to explain. I'm trying to perform multiple regression from a total of around 160 decimal lists that contain the observation data. I need a minimum of 2 lists for the formula and a max of 10 lists for the formula and I'm trying to figure out how I can run this calculation for all possible combinations of decimal lists. Here is some code that I have so far and I'm trying to turn this code into

```
var matrixArray = CreateMatrix.DenseOfColumnArrays(listMRInfo.ElementAt(0).ListValues.ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(1).ListValues.ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(2).ListValues.ToArray(), 
listMRInfo.ElementAt(3).ListValues.ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(4).ListValues.ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(5).ListValues.ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(6).ListValues.ToArray(), 
listMRInfo.ElementAt(7).ListValues.ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(8).ListValues.ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(9).ListValues.ToArray(), listMRInfo.ElementAt(10).ListValues.ToArray());
var items = MultipleRegression.NormalEquations(matrixArray, vectorArray);
var estimatedList = new List<double>();
var y = calcTemp.CalculateYIntercept(matrixArray, vectorArray.ToList(), items);

  for (int i = 0; i < listMRInfo.First().ListValues.Count; i++)
     {
       var estimate = (items.ElementAt(0) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(0).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(1) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(1).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) +
                                (items.ElementAt(2) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(2).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(3) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(3).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) +
                                (items.ElementAt(4) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(4).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(5) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(5).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) +
                                (items.ElementAt(6) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(6).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(7) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(7).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) +
                                (items.ElementAt(8) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(8).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + (items.ElementAt(9) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(9).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) +
                                (items.ElementAt(10) * listMRInfo.ElementAt(10).ListValues.ElementAt(i)) + y;
                            estimatedList.Add(estimate);
     }

    var rss = calcTemp.CalculateResidualSumOfSquares(estimatedList, vectorArray.ToList());
    var tss = calcTemp.CalculateTotalSumOfSquares(vectorArray.ToList());
    var rSquared = 1 - (rss / tss);
```

I'm trying to run the above code for each possible combination of lists. Please let me know if you need me to explain anything

Comment: What you're doing is a pretty reasonable start, but working in C# is maybe a little clumsy. Can you use R? http://r-project.org What you're trying to do is called variable selection. Note that rSquared(S2) > rSquared(S1) for two subsets of variables S1 contained in S2 and S1 != S2, i.e. adding more variables to a subset always increases rSquared, so maybe you only need to look at the largest (most variables) subsets, unless your criterion is something other than rSquared. R probably already has a package to carry out variable selection. The user mailing list for R (r-users) is very helpful.

Comment: @RobertDodier I would prefer R but I'm afraid the project is required with C# so I'm not sure how to do variable selection with C# then

Comment: Well, I think a straightforward separation of tasks into functions should work. One task is to generate possible combinations of variables. Another is to iterate over the list, and a third is to compute the regression coefficients and/or rSquared, and a fourth is to rank the combinations by their corresponding rSquared values. Note that there are a tremendous number of combinations; something greater than (160 choose 10) which is 160!/10!/150! i.e. very large, so you will probably have to choose combinations at random, or else find some way to prune the search. I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: It occurs to me that there might already be some libraries in C# for statistics.